# AMD Crimson driver low fps Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati

So, today I installed the new AMD crimson driver. AMD mentioned, that this driver increases perfomance of several games including DotA2. Before installing this driver I run open source driver with opengl 4.1 which was giving me about 80-100 FPS in dota, but the new one (Crimson) could make only 50-70.

After installing the new driver I opened CCC to make sure I'm using the right one now.
My HW specs are:

- CPU: AMD FX4350 running at it's default speed, not
  OCed.
- GPU: Radeon R9 270 Dual-X 2GB
- RAM: 8GB
- OS: Ubuntu 15.10

So the qeustion is: is this the fault of AMD who seems not to care about poor linux users or it's that I just installed everything in a wrong way? Have someone installed the same driver already, what are your results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you made a mistake, since you were able to still play the game (no crash).

Chances are you were affected by what Michael over at [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd-crimson-linux&num=1) found out too. To quote him:

> Well, even with BioShock Infinite which is supposed to be faster on Radeon Software 15.11 for Linux, none of the three graphics cards tested saw any performance gains. **The only dramatic performance differences found with this new driver was in the Metro Redux games where the performance changes were regressions.**

So, yeah, sadly AMD still has a long way to go with their Linux drivers. :(

Comment: thank you very much! Looks like there is no other choice than bying Nvidia graphics card. Sad but true, AMD, I was your fan.

Comment: I hear you. Used to only buy AMD. Now I am Intel and Nvidia.